# How to give Dynamic value for array destruction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I need that kind of thing. but I don't want to write that 6 lines manually but instead of that I want to write some loop thing so I can easily get that all six value from one line

```
console.log(array[0].name.LINE1)
console.log(array[0].name.LINE2)
console.log(array[0].name.LINE3)
console.log(array[1].name.LINE1)
console.log(array[1].name.LINE2)
console.log(array[1].name.LINE3)
```

From the array

```js
const array = [{name: {LINE1: "1.5", LINE2: "1.1", LINE3: "1.6"}}, 
               {name: {LINE1: "2.5", LINE2: "1.8", LINE3: "1.4"}}]
```

So I try to do this thing like

```js
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    console.log(array[i].name.LINE{i+1})
}
```

but it doesn't work, can anyone give me a solution how can I destruct that array with the dynamic value?
How I can take the value from the array to writing one line instead of that 6 lines??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log all of the lines you can use `.forEach` to loop over the objects inside the `array` and then loop over the lines properties inside the `name` object

```js
const array = [
  {
    name: {LINE1: "1.5", LINE2: "1.1", LINE3: "1.6"}
  }, {
    name: {LINE1: "2.5", LINE2: "1.8", LINE3: "1.4"}
  }
];

array.forEach(obj => {
  for(let line in obj.name) {
    console.log(`${line}: ${obj.name[line]}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `forEach` and `Object.values`

```js
const array = [{name: {LINE1: "1.5", LINE2: "1.1", LINE3: "1.6"}}, 
               {name: {LINE1: "2.5", LINE2: "1.8", LINE3: "1.4"}}]
               

array.forEach(({name}) => console.log(Object.values(name)))

array.forEach(({name}) => console.log(Object.entries(name)))
```